# Default value of class in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class :

```cpp
class InterruptDevice
{
public:
    InterruptDevice();
    InterruptDevice(USHORT deviceAddress);
    ~InterruptDevice();
    USHORT deviceAddress;
    bool obsolete;
    std::map<USHORT, std::vector<HIDReportDescriptorInputParse>> inputparser;
    std::map<BYTE, std::vector<BYTE>> endpoints;T
};
```

where `HIDReportDescriptorInputParse` is struct :

```cpp
typedef struct HIDReportDescriptorInputParse
{
    HIDReportDescriptorInputParse() : inputSize(0), reportDefined(false), reportID(0), deviceAddress(0),
        globalItemUsage(0), localItemUsage(0)
    {
    }
    int inputSize;
    bool reportDefined;
    uint32_t reportID;
    uint32_t globalItemUsage;
    uint32_t localItemUsage;
    USHORT deviceAddress;
    std::vector<InputValues> inputValues;
} HIDReportDescriptorInputParse, * PHIDReportDescriptorInputParse;

typedef struct InputValues
{
    InputValues() : GlobalUsagePage(0), ReportSize(0), ReportCount(0), UsageMinimum(0), UsageMaximum(0),
        LogicalMinimum(0), LogicalMaximum(0), Variable(true)
    {
    }
    std::vector<uint32_t> LocalUsageNames;
    uint32_t GlobalUsagePage;
    uint32_t ReportSize;
    uint32_t ReportCount;
    uint32_t UsageMinimum;
    uint32_t UsageMaximum;
    uint32_t LogicalMinimum;
    uint32_t LogicalMaximum;
    bool Variable;
}InputValues, * PInputValues;
```

Now, I want to have a class which takes `InterruptDevice` as a constructor argument, but I dont want it to be mandatory, so I need default argument value. Can it be written like this :

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A(int a, InterruptDevice device = InterruptDevice());
}
```

When I try this, it works, but I am afraid of some undefined behaviour. Is this correct way how to do this ?

Comment: It will work, nothing wrong with this approach. You could also make 2 constructors for A, one that has InterruptDevice in params, and one that doesn't.

Comment: Should be correct. (You have a custom `~InterruptDevice()` so you have to respect rule of 3/5).

Comment: This could help I think https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constructors-cpp?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 1):

You can define alternative constructor or you can use defaults, that's usually a design choice. Creation of default value is an added cost though.

Additionally, to avoid repeating code and initialization lists, you can delegate one constructor to another, calling it in beginning of initialization list. The delegated constructor is one that would have  base class's initialization.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you also want a constructor A() in class A, correct?
As such your implementation of that constructor could be something like

```
A::A()
{
   a = 0;
   InterruptDevice device = InterruptDevice();
};
```

In the InterruptDevice() constructor you can define in a similar way how to initialize your member variables as you've done for `HIDReportDescriptorInputParse`.